# Woocommerce shop doesnt display the products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing issue in WordPress woocommerce. The **shop** page doesn't display the products

Steps that I followed

- I have installed Woocommerce in my WordPress project
- I've added theme support in functions.php
- I have added the woocommerce pages from the plugin tools.
  and imported default products
- I created a separate folder named woocommerce in my theme folder and added archive-product.php file.

But when I open the frontend shop page it doesn't display the products.

and the shop page is still targetting index.php

help me solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this again:
Copy the entire template folder into your theme \ woocommerce folder

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured it out, now I get to see the list of products in the shop page.

thinking there might be a conflict with directory name and the page name I changed my WordPress address and site URL and directory from

http://localhost/shop

TO

http://localhost/shop1

now

http://localhost/shop1/index.php/shop
I get to see the list of products and the theme name is reflecting archive-product.php